# Outlook 2010 via wine is installed, but can't add an account / Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I have installed MS Office 2010 using wine on Ubuntu 14.04. When I open Outlook and try to add new account, I see following:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/e0d8c2344431849

I press "Add account" and "Account settings -> Account settings", but nothing happens.
Could someone help me with this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @RonSmith - How about you? did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, gave up and used the crappy MS Webmail.

Comment: @RonSmith - I think the key here is finding some registry key to delete, since Windows users seem to to have had this problem too,

Comment: Have you tried using playonlinux.com to install the Office 2010? Also have you edited the config.xml" file under the "ProPlus.WW" to your product key? 

http://sovidence.blogspot.com/2013/03/installing-office-2010-in-linux-solving.html

Comment: Thunderbird (with EWS Addon) and Evolution are totally capable of connecting to any Exchange Server. Why installing M$ Software on a pretty fine linux System?

Answer (score 1):

Ok  so You could use a virtual machine to solve this, in which case, you would have the windows control panel, and the "mail" applet, where you could configure an address manually. I might be safe to assume that the same issue wouldn't be happening in the first place within a virtual machine, but if it were, again, you would have access to the control panel, where you could implement instructions like [these](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Add-an-email-account-by-using-advanced-settings-df811069-5942-47d4-9197-0ff14e904b31?CorrelationId=2a1c17da-4570-4ebe-b0a8-08f59e3c68e2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for manually adding a mail account.

Unfortunately, wine doesn't have the control panel in the same way that MS windows has it.
It does have [Control.exe](http://wiki.winehq.org/control) its own implementation which doesn't offer the same features. I dont personaly have outlook 2010, but you could look to see if you have a Mail icon in the wine control panel `$wine control`  presumably if you do have it, you can use it to edit your mail settings manually. I have no way to know that.

I want to note that Linux offers a wide array of e-mail clients, such as Evolution. which will work natively.

You might try some of the applications in the programs folder for outlook to troubleshoot the installation. like safemode.  perhaps you will be able to install via safemode. see the folder:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\

A corrupt pst file could also create errors for outlook. Try running scanpst.exe (from the office14 folder)

Finlay if none of those work, you could try editing the pst file. 
many free pst file editors exist. The PST file is were outlook stores its data on users and contacts. You may have to do some hacking on the pst file to manually create new users. Its been about 3 years since Ive even looked at outlook. http://www.ehow.com/how_6064889_edit-pst-file.html

Back up your pst files before you edit them. Good luck.

Comment: Empathy? Did you mean Evolution?

Comment: yes, thats is what I meant

Answer (score 0):

On office 2010, it is located in (your wine folder location)/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/MLCFG32.CPL

you then have to run it using rundll32

EDIT (for Office 2010 on Wine):

This is an attempt to solve the weird problem when you want to setup & Configure manually a Exchange account during related the wizard:  It tells you that you cannot do that while outlook is running!

So you have to close outlook and try to make that window appear outside outlook which means "go to the control panel" in a regular windows install.

To simulate a click to the control panel icon, you have to do the following

```
export WINEPREFIX="/home/$(whoami)/.wineprefixes/office2010/"
export WINEARCH="win32"
```

(those 2 exports forces wine to execute in 32bits, see the link below)
then (**from the c:\windows folder**)

```
~/.wine/drive_c/windows$ wine rundll32.exe  shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL  "/home/nadir/.wineprefixes/office2010/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/MLCFG32.CPL"
```

**"wineprefixes"** folder is where I installed office following a good tutorial (Office 2010 fully working on wine) that you can find here : http://nithinaneeshsct06bt.blogspot.fr/2013/02/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html
You'll also see why the 2 exports.

Results: the "Email" control panel window **appears(!)**, but...you cannot go further unfortunately.

For the record, here is the message from wine when I click on the "exchange account button"

```
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsA (0x5e6a720, 0x6015a40, {8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 1, 0x33e924, (null), (null), 0x6015a40,): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsA (0x5e6a720, 0x6005a40, {f94cbe33-31c2-492d-9bf8-573beff84c94}, 1, 0x33e9e4, (null), (null), 0x6005a40,): stub
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {9240a6d2-af41-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676} of class {ed475414-b0d6-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676}, hres is 0x80040605
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {9240a6d2-af41-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676} of class {ed475414-b0d6-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676}, hres is 0x80040605
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {9240a6d2-af41-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676} of class {ed475414-b0d6-11d2-8c3b-00104b2a6676}, hres is 0x80040605
```

Comment: Note: running OS is XUbuntu 14.04

Comment: for the record, the error messages returned when I click on to open the exchange account settings:

Comment: **Fixed!**.
The idea is to export a reg file, from my original  windows laptop, in  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook
then import it in wine (wine regedit then menu "import") - 

Now when you launch outlook again, **the account is there**, you just have to retype the password, and fix the folder issues (where incoming emails go).

( idea borrowed from 
http://superuser.com/questions/471419/how-do-i-export-email-account-settings-from-outlook-2010 )

- Outlook seems not very stable, I manage anyway to receive & send emails

Answer (score -1):

This helped me

~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14> wine rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL MLCFG32.CPL

but outlook 2010 work unstable on wine 4.4, with many errors